# Pick first date before match and until another match is found

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling a little bit trying to convert a regex that is working with grep into Python.

Basically it is a non-binary file so it's really messy inside, log messages.

What I want to do is have a match, look behind for the first time stamp found and then look ahead until certain match.

Le me put an example.

**The text**

> 23:31:57.968: VERBOSE: Heartbeat from NanoPC received  23:54:07.968: INFORMATION: InformationEventTriggered#123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP) ClientID: 1 23:55:57.968: VERBOSE: Heartbeat from NanoPC received 23:56:57.968: VERBOSE: Heartbeat from NanoPC received 23:59:07.968: WARNING: WarningEventTriggered#123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP) ClientID: 1

**Expected output**

Capture every time InformationEventTriggered or WarningEventTriggered is written, take the timestamp to the left and select everything until clientID.
In this example, two matches:

1. 23:31:57.968: VERBOSE: Heartbeat from NanoPC received 23:54:07.968: INFORMATION: InformationEventTriggered#123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP)
2. 23:59:07.968: WARNING: WarningEventTriggered#123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP)

**What have I tried**
I am using re Python:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}.*)(InformationEventTriggered\#|WarningEventTriggered\#).*(?=ClientID)
```

The first group to pick the dates, then everything (.*) until the Event messages, to the clientID.

Sadly, it's not working: https://regex101.com/r/dPCDtz/1

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:(?:(?!\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:).)*?)((?:Information|Warning)EventTriggered#)(.*?)(?=ClientID|\Z)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/THhhhH/2), details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:(?:(?!\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:).)*?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}` - 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits,`.`, 3 digits
  - `:` - a colon
  - `(?:(?!\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:).)*?` - any char, 0+ occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start a sequence of the initial patterns (see above)
- `((?:Information|Warning)EventTriggered#)` - Group 2: `Information` or `|Warning` and then `EventTriggered#`
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(?=ClientID|\Z)` - up to the first occurrence of `ClientID` or end of string.

[Python snippet](https://ideone.com/rndIJi):

```
import re
text = "your string"
rx = re.compile(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:(?:(?!\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}:).)*?)((?:Information|Warning)EventTriggered#)(.*?)(?=ClientID|\Z)', re.S)
for m in re.finditer(rx, text):
    print("Group 1: {}".format(m.group(1)))
    print("Group 2: {}".format(m.group(2)))
    print("Group 3: {}".format(m.group(3)))
```

Output:

```
Group 1: 23:54:07.968: INFORMATION: 
Group 2: InformationEventTriggered#
Group 3: 123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP) 
Group 1: 23:59:07.968: WARNING: 
Group 2: WarningEventTriggered#
Group 3: 123 (serverIP:Unknown, protocol:TCP)
```

Comment: This pretty much works, I just need a little tweak sometimes before the hour (first \d{2}) there is a random number and letters becuase logs are not parsed OK.

See second entry here, https://regex101.com/r/THhhhH/3, is there any way to handle it?

Comment: @AlejandroA You may remove `\b` then. See https://regex101.com/r/THhhhH/4